# How I can change writing direction

Tags: magento2.3, language, multi-language, language-switcher

How I can change language direction from left to right to right to left, I want to make magento in ara

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue, if you have multi store one of is Arabic, then create a style.css for Arabic store and add **direction: rtl** in styles.css . It will automatically change its direction.